# What would cause a compressed database dump to be broken into two stacks (or segments)?

Tags: sap-ase

I've been trying determine the uncompressed size of a compressed database dump.  I've been able to use the lsize in the dump header information to do this.  In my testing I have created an empty test database in the following way:

```
create database foo on default=100
```

We are using master as the default.  I realize this is not a production-realistic scenario.  Then I created a dump of the database like this:

```
dump database foo to '/var/tmp/foo_compressed_9.dmp' with compression=9
```

I noticed the header shows there are two segments (pardon if my terminology is wrong):

```
segmap: 0x00000007 lstart=0 vstart=[vpgdevno=0 vpvpn=61444] lsize=5120 unrsvd=4240
segmap: 0x00000007 lstart=5120 vstart=[vpgdevno=0 vpvpn=68612] lsize=33536 unrsvd=33405
```

Most dumps I've seen have only one segment (one "segmap:" line in the header).  What conditions could cause a dump to have two of them?  Could there ever be more than two, and what would cause that?

Thanks

Comment: How many `devices` does `database foo` uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Segmap` is related to the `devices` used by a `database`.

In you case, the `database foo` should have two `devices` (maybe one for `data` and another for `log`) and that's why there are two `Segmap`.

You may use the following `query` to see how many devices are used by `database foo`:

```
select distinct s.name, u.segmap from master..sysusages u
inner join master..sysdatabases s on u.dbid = s.dbid and s.name = 'foo'
```